# max width of inside div not working

Tags: html, css

just practising with the `max-width` property in CSS. In the following code, the inside div `.topimage` (the one with red color) is not appearing at all even after setting `max-width: 960px;max-height: 200px;` What could be the reason? Please note, I am using max width/height because I want the inside div to scale according to the size of browser window.

```css
html,body {
 margin: 0px;
 height: 100%;
 width: 100%;
 left: 0px;
 top: 0px;
 background-color: rgba(173,192,241,1);
    }

.wrapper {
 height: 800px;
 max-width: 960px;
 margin-left: auto;
 left: 0px;
 top: 0px;
 margin-right: auto;
 position: relative;
}



.topimage {
 max-width: 960px;
 max-height: 200px;
 background-color: rgba(255,0,0,1);
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
<div class="topimage">
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need width and height.

Max-width doesn't spread you div.

use width: 100%, max-width: 960px;

and for height you need  to have a content inside or to put height:100px, for example.

Answer (score 1):

By default, an empty DIV has width set to 100% and height set to 0px, hence the height is not affected by your max, therefore you can't see the red box.

A simple fix is just adding 100% as the default, and then max-width/height can come into play. *(You don't **need** to specify width as the default is usually 100%, but it's good practise to state your own defaults).*

```css
html,body {
 margin: 0px;
 height: 100%;
 width: 100%;
 left: 0px;
 top: 0px;
 background-color: rgba(173,192,241,1);
    }

.wrapper {
 height: 800px;
 max-width: 960px;
 margin-left: auto;
 left: 0px;
 top: 0px;
 margin-right: auto;
 position: relative;
}



.topimage {
 width:100%; /* ADDED */
 height:100%; /* ADDED */
 max-width: 960px;
 max-height: 200px;
 background-color: rgba(255,0,0,1);
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
<div class="topimage">
</div>
</div>
```